# A good way to create a shortcut selection field for use in a Mac app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I need to have a way for the user to input a shortcut key combination in my Preferences and I'm looking to do something that works similar to how the System Preferences keyboard shortcut panel works.

I thought about subclassing an `NSTextField` and override `keyDown:` and `keyUp:` but it seems  these overrides do nothing... any hints?

Alternatively is there a control kit or some technique that everyone is using and I haven't heard of? Quite a few applications implement a similar behavior albeit with some slight "look-and-feel" differences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Shortcut Recorder](http://code.google.com/p/shortcutrecorder/).

Comment: Yea, Shortcut Recorder is the way to go.